# Shopify Image Uploads failing using GraphQL API

Tags: python, automation, graphql, shopify, shopify-api

I'm rewriting a script to upload large batches of images to Shopify using the GraphQL API. I keep running into two issues, the first is images that upload successfully do not process properly. The second issue is I hit the rate limit and the script breaks out of the loop despite having exponential rate limiting. I've tried rate limiting and using different queries in GQL to facilitate the upload and I've identified the appropriate one. I have everything broken down into classes > definitions to make things easier to work with. Outside of this class is where I get the necessary data for the GQL queries.
Apologies if this is too much code to work with, I'm not sure if its all necessary but it is all used when executing this portion of the script. f

Edit1 - Log output:

> Checking file: GCE#30014_1.jpg
> Checking file: GCE#30014_1.jpg
> Extracted SKU: 30014
> Attempting to upload image: C:/Users/Ej/Desktop/ebay9-24-23/exports\GCE#30014_1.jpg for SKU: 30014
> https://shopify-staged-uploads.storage.googleapis.com/tmp/82023907619/products/89987676-445a-482e-a025-4d234f2f716d/GCE_30014_1.jpg?X-Goog-Algorithm=GOOG4-RSA-SHA256&X-Goog-Credential=merchant-assets%40shopify-tiers.iam.gserviceaccount.com%2F20230929%2Fauto%2Fstorage%2Fgoog4_request&X-Goog-Date=20230929T185717Z&X-Goog-Expires=604800&X-Goog-SignedHeaders=host&X-Goog-Signature=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
> Successfully uploaded image for SKU 30014 at position 1. Image ID: None, Image URL: None

Error from Shopify -

> Media Upload Fail - Image: Media processing failed

```
class ShopifyPhotoUploader:
    def __init__(self, connection):
        self.connection = connection
        self.missing_photos = []
        self.successfully_uploaded = []

    def select_folder(self):
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.withdraw()
        folder_selected = filedialog.askdirectory()
        return folder_selected

    def generate_staged_uploads(self, image_path):
        original_filename = os.path.basename(image_path)
        file_size = os.path.getsize(image_path)

        # Define backoff parameters
        max_retries = 5
        base_delay = 5  # in seconds
        max_delay = 60  # in seconds

        # GraphQL mutation for generating staged uploads
        mutation = """
        mutation generateStagedUploads($input: [StagedUploadInput!]!) {
            stagedUploadsCreate(input: $input) {
                stagedTargets {
                    url
                    resourceUrl
                    parameters {
                        name
                        value
                    }
                }
                userErrors {
                    field
                    message
                }
            }
        }
        """

        # Variables for the mutation
        variables = {
            "input": [
                {
                    "filename": original_filename,
                    "mimeType": "image/jpg",
                    "resource": "IMAGE",
                    "fileSize": str(file_size)
                }
            ]
        }

        for attempt in range(max_retries):
            try:
                # Send the mutation to Shopify
                response = self.connection.make_request(mutation, variables)

                if not response:
                    raise Exception("No response received from Shopify.")

                # Handle the response
                if 'data' in response and 'stagedUploadsCreate' in response['data']:
                    staged_targets = response['data']['stagedUploadsCreate']['stagedTargets']
                    if staged_targets:
                        url = staged_targets[0]['url']
                        # If successful, break out of the loop
                        if url:
                            print(url)  # This will print the URL for your reference
                            return url
                else:
                    raise Exception("Failed to generate staged uploads")

            except Exception as e:
                # Handle exceptions that you expect, like rate limiting
                if "Throttled" in str(e) and attempt < max_retries - 1:
                    delay = min(base_delay * (2 ** attempt), max_delay)
                    print(f"Rate limited. Retrying in {delay} seconds...")
                    time.sleep(delay)
                else:
                    # If it's an unexpected exception or you've reached max retries, raise the exception
                    raise
        
        raise Exception("Max retries reached for generate_staged_uploads")


    def handle_staged_upload_response(self, response, original_filename):
        """Handle the response from the generate_staged_uploads function and extract the URL."""
        
        if not response:
            print(f"Error: No response received for {original_filename}.")
            return None, None
        
        # Check if the response contains the necessary data
        if 'data' in response and 'stagedUploadsCreate' in response['data']:
            staged_targets = response['data']['stagedUploadsCreate']['stagedTargets']
            
            # Check if stagedTargets contains any data
            if staged_targets:
                url = staged_targets[0]['url']
                resource_url = staged_targets[0]['resourceUrl']
                return url, resource_url
            else:
                print(f"Error: No staged targets found in the response for {original_filename}.")
                return None, None
        else:
            print(f"Error: Invalid response format for {original_filename}.")
            return None, None



    def upload_images_from_folder(self, folder_path, SKUandProductID):
        print(f"Starting upload process from folder: {folder_path}")
        print("SKUandProductID List:", SKUandProductID)
        
        # Iterate through files in the folder and subfolders
        for root, _, files in os.walk(folder_path):
            for file in files:
                print(f"Checking file: {file}")
                # Check if the file matches the naming scheme "GCE#20001_1.jpg"
                match = re.match(r'GCE#(\d+)_(\d+)\.jpg', file)
                if match:
                    sku, position = match.groups()

                    print(f"Checking file: {file}")
                    print(f"Extracted SKU: {sku}")

                    ##product_id = next((item['product_id'] for item in SKUandProductID if item['sku'] == sku), None)
                    product_id = next((item[1] for item in SKUandProductID if item[0] == sku), None)
                    if product_id:
                        full_image_path = os.path.join(root, file)
                        print(f"Attempting to upload image: {full_image_path} for SKU: {sku}")
                        if self.upload_image(product_id, full_image_path, int(position), sku):
                            self.successfully_uploaded.append({'product_id': product_id, 'sku': sku})
                    else:
                        print(f"Missing product ID for SKU: {sku}")
                        self.missing_photos.append(sku)
                else:
                    print(f"File {file} does not match the expected naming scheme.")
        # Create a log file for SKUs without photos
        if self.missing_photos:
            print(f"Logging SKUs without photos to 'missing_photos.log'")
            with open('missing_photos.log', 'w') as log_file:
                log_file.write("\n".join(self.missing_photos))

        # Update metafields for successfully uploaded images
        for item in self.successfully_uploaded:
            print(f"Updating metafield for product ID: {item['product_id']}")
            self.update_metafield(item['product_id'], "custom", "photo_shoot_", "True")

    def upload_image(self, product_id, image_path, position, sku):
        """Upload an image to Shopify using GraphQL."""
        # Encode the image to base64
        ##with open(image_path, "rb") as image_file:
        ##    encoded_image = base64.b64encode(image_file.read()).decode('utf-8')
        staged_url = self.generate_staged_uploads(image_path)
        
        # GraphQL mutation for uploading the image
        mutation = """
        mutation productCreateMedia($media: [CreateMediaInput!]!, $productId: ID!) {
            productCreateMedia(media: $media, productId: $productId) {
                media {
                    alt
                    mediaContentType
                    status
                }
                mediaUserErrors {
                    field
                    message
                }
                product {
                    id
                    title
                }
            }
        }
        """

        # Variables for the mutation
        variables = {
            "media": [
                {
                    "alt": f"{sku}",
                    "mediaContentType": "IMAGE",
                    "originalSource": f"{staged_url}"
                }
            ],
            "productId": f"{product_id}"
        }

        # Send the mutation to Shopify
        response = self.connection.make_request(mutation, variables)
        
        if response:
            data = response
        else:
            print(f"Error: No response received when uploading image for SKU:{sku}_{position}.")
            return False
        
        # Check for errors
        user_errors = data.get('data', {}).get('productCreateMedia', {}).get('mediaUserErrors', [])
        if user_errors:
            for error in user_errors:
                field = error.get('field', 'Unknown field')
                message = error.get('message', 'Unknown error')
                print(f"Error uploading image for SKU {sku} at position {position}: {field} - {message}")
            return False
        else:
            image_id = data.get('data', {}).get('productCreateMedia', {}).get('media', [{}])[0].get('id')
            image_src = data.get('data', {}).get('productCreateMedia', {}).get('media', [{}])[0].get('src')
            print(f"Successfully uploaded image for SKU {sku} at position {position}. Image ID: {image_id}, Image URL: {image_src}")
            return True
```